# Plotting Confidence Bands for Single Variables?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

I performed a multiple linear regression and calculated upper and lower 95% confidence intervals for all coefficients. It looks like this:

```
variable    coefficient     lower 95% CI     upper 95% CI
const       +100            98                102
x1          5               3                 7               
x2          10              5                 15
```

Now I want to visualize the effect of ONE variable on the dependent variable. This can be done easily. For example for x2 you can plot the function y=10*x2. This is a straight line and it shows the expected changes in the dependent variable when you increase x2 and hold all other vairables constant.

Here is my problem: x2 is the expected value of the coefficient, so there is uncertainity associated with it. Is it sensible to plot the upper and lower 95% CI for the coefficient? Meaning, you plot y=10*x2 and for the upper and lower CIs you plot y=5*x2 and y=15*x2?

I am still not sure about it, because I haven't found a paper where this has been done.

Comment: Do you have any preferred programming language or statistical software?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python. Can you recommend something?

Comment: My GIF animations of 95% confidence intervals illustrating several common curve fitting problems may have some Python code you can use: http://zunzun.com/CommonProblems/ with the Python source code at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/CommonProblems